# Views single field themeing with custom variables

Tags: 7, views, theming

How do I pass a variable from a preprocess hook to a template file for a single field, that is view files starting with

> views-view-field--

I want to know what are the preprocess functions that can be used for this purpose. Because, whenever I try to set a variable using `hook_preprocess_views_view_fields` it is only renderable at sytle/row level, but never at single field level.

Hope Im clear with my query. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just that there are two similarly-named theme implementations: `views_view_field` and `views_view_fields` (trailing *s*). Generally you can take the name of the template file before the first double-dash to find the theme implementation name, so if the template starts with `views-view-field--` you'd expect the preprocess to be `hook_preprocess_views_view_field()`. (That naming pattern's not guaranteed though.)

Comment: What was I thinking? **duh**  Thanks a lot man, works like a charm.